# Gson Ignoring Instance Creator

Tags: gson

I am defining an `InstanceCreator` and registering it via the `GsonBuilder` like so:

```
final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(java.awt.Shape.class, new ShapeInstanceCreator<>());
final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

However, I still receive the following error, and never see the `InstanceCreator` being called when deserializing the JSON:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface java.awt.Shape. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
```

Is there any reason why this would be ignored?